# Mapbox GL - toggle-highlight specific feature on hover using the map style

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Id like to highlight a specific feature of a layer which is included in my map style when hover.. something like this:

```
  map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var states = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
     layers: ['n_Region6 Municipals']
    });
    if (states.length > 0) {      
      map.setPaintProperty('n_Region6 Municipals', 'fill-color',' 
      {"property":"NAME_2","type":"category","stops": + 
      [[states[0].properties.NAME_2 +,"blue"]]}');    
      });
```

with setpaintproperty paired with data driven function I got no luck..
I tried with Filter with this.

```
      map.addLayer({
          "id": "state-fills",
          "type": "fill",
          "source": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mapbox://noeltech.c8nzzthb"
          },
          "source-layer":"R6_Pop_byMunicipal-5cqj12",
          "layout": {},
          "paint": {
                        "fill-color": "#627BC1",
                        "fill-opacity": 0
       }
   });
   map.addLayer({
    "id": "state-fills-hover",
    "type": "line",
    "source": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mapbox://noeltech.c8nzzthb"
    },
    "source-layer":"R6_Pop_byMunicipal-5cqj12",
    "layout": {},
    "paint": {
      "line-color": "#627BC1",
      "line-width": 3
    },
    "filter": ["==", "NAME_2", ""]
  });
 //  map.setLayoutProperty('n_Region6 Municipals', 'visibility', 'none');

});
 map.on("mousemove", "state-fills", function(e) {
    map.setFilter("state-fills-hover", ["==", "NAME_2", 
   e.features[0].properties.NAME_2]);
```

it does what i want to do but it makes me add another layer and I dont want that. i want to use the layer in my map style.like the first code.
how to do it in simple code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `"type":"categorical"`

and the syntax would be

```
map.setPaintProperty('n_Region6 Municipals', 'fill-color',{
  "property":"NAME_2",
  "type":"categorical",
  "stops":[
    [states[0].properties.NAME_2,"blue"],
    ],
  "default": "red"
});
```

Comment: This could work..didn't try it yet cause I got it working with passing an object carrying the fill-color parameters

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this code:

```
    var highlight =   {
           property: 'NAME_2',
           type: "categorical",
           stops: [[MunicipalName, 'blue']]
         };
   map.setPaintProperty('n_Region6 Municipals', 'fill-color', highlight);
```

the problem now is I didn't consider that it would color the rest of polygon black. IS there any simple way how to highlight a single feature without adding more layers?
[Highlights blue but change all the colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyDHS.jpg)

Comment: yes. you set the `default` color to a color that is translucent i.e. `rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: but i want the rest to remain the same as they were..maybe data driven function  is not the answer for highlighting features within the map style.

Comment: you could use data-driven styling – you would have to set default to the current value of the rest of the features, but this is not the most performant approach because it involves recomputing the feature attribute buffers for every single feature in the layer when you only need to change one feature. I would use 2 layers with `filter`s instead.

Comment: Thanks for saying that two layers and filter approach..it helps a lot someone from Mapbox confirming that is the best way to do it at this moment..